# Can #if pre-processor directives be nested in C++?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I have a question about Pre-processor directives in c++:

For example:

```
#ifndef QUESTION

//some code here

#ifndef QUESTION

//some code here

#endif

#endif
```

Can we use it in this way, and can the C++ compiler match the `ifndef` and `endif` in the right way?

Comment: You can nest conditionals, and you can call one macro from another but you can't nest macros directly, e.g. `#define AAA #define XXX` - it won't work correctly.

Comment: Since [a C question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38963852/827263) was just closed as a duplicate of this one, I'll point out that rules for the C and C++ preprocessor are the same, at least as far as this question is concerned.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Yes, we can. The `#endif` statement matches to the previous `#if` `#ifdef` or `#ifndef` etc for which there hasn't been a corresponding `#endif`.

e.g.

```
#if  ----------|
#if  -----|    |
#endif ---|    |
#endif --------|
```

Comment: we have two #endif here, so the first #endif will match the second #ifndef?

Comment: It won't match the previous one; that would mean we *couldn't* nest them.

Answer (score 65):

Yes, you can nest `#if`/`#endif` blocks. Some C coding styles would tell you to write

```
#ifdef CONDITION1
# ifdef CONDITION2
# endif
#endif
```

using spaces to denote the level of nesting.

Comment: +1 for the nesting bit, it helps a lot with clarity sometimes.

Comment: Why would you insert space? why not just indent the `#ifdef`

Comment: I didn't even know spaces between `#` and preprocessor directives were allowed. Big thanks for that tip!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the #ifndef QUESTION section will be discarded unless you #undef QUESTION.

Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, misread the code sample! I thought it started with #ifdef QUESTION