# C preprocessor macro embedded #ifdef #endif

Tags: macros

Can you embed #ifdef and #endif?

For example:

```
#ifdef B
    run1();
    #ifdef C
        run2();
    #endif
#endif
```

Desired result is run2() only occurs if both B and C are defined

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can if preprocessor directives be nested in c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678396/can-if-preprocessor-directives-be-nested-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

[See the official GCC documentation for details](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Ifdef.html#Ifdef).

> The controlled text inside of a conditional can include preprocessing directives. They are executed only if the conditional succeeds. **You can nest conditional groups inside other conditional groups**, but they must be completely nested. In other words, ‘#endif’ always matches the nearest ‘#ifdef’ (or ‘#ifndef’, or ‘#if’). Also, you cannot start a conditional group in one file and end it in another.