# Nested #else handling in false #ifdef in C

Tags: c, compiler-construction, macros, c-preprocessor

How should a C compiler handle a #else directive that corresponds to a #ifdef directive inside another #ifdef that evaluates to false? In other, words in the code below should code C get executed because the compiler thinks the #else corresponds with the first #ifdef? Or should it be 'smart' enough to know that all of the 2nd #ifdef is nested inside the false evaluation of the 1st #ifdef?

```
#undefine FLAG1

#ifdef FLAG1
//code section 1
#ifdef FLAG2
//code section 2
#else
//code section 3
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: As noted in the dup, the else will go with the FLAG2 check.  Use your #endifs at the right places to dictate the path you want.

Comment: @Joe Nice dup find! Nice question, too bad its already answered.

Comment: The dup is about C++ not C, but the preprocessor behaves the same way as far as this example is concerned.